# Begin a glob with an exclude pattern

Tags: bash, wildcards

I am trying to tweak some [completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html). Suppose I have:

```
$ ls
bar.baz  foo_bar.baz  foo.bar
```

If I want completion to match all files that don't end in baz:

```
$ shopt|grep extglob
extglob         on
$ compgen -G "*.!(baz)"
foo.bar
```

The exclude glob works as expected. But if I want all files that don't start with foo:

```
$ compgen -G "!(foo)*"
bar.baz
foo.bar
foo_bar.baz
```

All the files still match. Presumably this is because the `*` can still expand to match `foo`. Is there a glob trick to use exclusion followed by `*`?

As Janis pointed out, excluding foo needs to be `!(foo*)`, but the actual use case is to also match on an extension, so the glob needs to be generally of the form `!(foo*)*.bar` (which still fails to exclude "foo" prefixes).

Answer (score 6):

You have to include the `*` in the negation, e.g.:

```
ls !(foo*)
```

Edit (to clarify): The requested [extended] globbing pattern is `!(foo*)`. If used with the command `compgen` the call would be, e.g.:

```
compgen -G "!(foo*)"
```

You need quotes to pass the pattern to the command `compgen` unexpanded.

Edit (after question change): For your complete pattern in your edited question try one of `@(!(foo*)|*bar)` or `@(!(bar*)|*foo)`. (See my comment below if that isn't what you expect.)

Comment: This seems super obvious when I read it, but `man bash`  for `complete` says "The arguments to the -G ... options ... should be quoted to protect them from expansion before the complete builtin is invoked." IIUC when used unquoted this expands and sets completion based only on current matches to the pattern (rather than setting the glob itself as a completion pattern). If I use `compgen -G "!(foo)*"` it still matches everything.

Comment: @jake, have you tried `compgen -G "!(foo*)"` instead of the sample you posted? (The star should be **inside** the paranthesis not outside!)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo in my comment. `compgen -G "!(foo*)*"` returns all of the files in the above example, rather than just `bar.baz`, as expected.

Comment: It works for just `"!(foo*)"` as shown in your answer, but my actual use case includes the extension ("match all files with extension `.foo` unless they start with `bar`")

Comment: It may be something like `@(!(foo*)|*bar)` or `@(!(bar*)|*foo)`. Though you confused me; in your edited question you write `!(foo*)*.bar`, but in your comment here you seem to say something that appears like the reverse. Please clarify what you mean; best supported with a set of significant test samples (like fo.bar, foo, fooo.bar, foooo, go.bar), and shown which ones shall be matched and which ones not.

Comment: I originally tried to simplify the question because I thought it was just a simple problem with the glob. The intermediate edit and the above comment were just meant to clarify the actual use case (match all files ending with a given extension, unless they have a certain prefix). I'll rewrite the question to be exactly my use case.

Comment: You are searching the pattern of "not starting with `foo` **and** not ending with `baz`"? - This could be `!(foo*|*baz)` then.